# Unit testing in Laravel5 - Error

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5

According to:

```
/**
 * Call the given URI and return the Response.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  string  $uri
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @param  array   $files
 * @param  array   $server
 * @param  string  $content
 * @param  bool    $changeHistory
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function call()
```

In order to pass headers, I set them in the `$server` parameter, which I'm doing like so:

```
public function testCreateLocation(){
  $response = $this->call('POST', '/api/v1/token', $this->test_token_request);
  $tokenObject = json_decode($response->getContent());

  /** Run the test */
  $response = $this->call('POST', '/api/v1/location', $this->test_1_create_tag,
    [], ['Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$tokenObject->token]);

  /** Read the response */
  $this->assertResponseOk();
}
```

However, when I run the unit test, I get the following error:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code$ php phpunit.phar tests/LocationModelTest.php
PHPUnit 4.6.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from /home/vagrant/Code/phpunit.xml.dist

EFF

Time: 3.75 seconds, Memory: 35.75Mb

There was 1 error:

1) LocationModelTest::testCreateLocation
InvalidArgumentException: An uploaded file must be an array or an instance of UploadedFile.
```

I've tried passing in `null` and an empty array as it states, but the error is never resolved. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you use files in your controller/request/other methods you launch? If yes, you should show their declaration

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Nope, no files are being uploaded. This test was to retrieve a new api JWT token, and then apply that to any subsequent api calls for testing authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem on Laravel 5.1 as well. Once I checked the up to date [documentation on the call() method](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html#method_call) I saw the issue though:

```
call(string $method, string $uri, array $parameters = array(), **array $cookies = array(),** array $files = array(), array $server = array(), string $content = null)
```

Somewhere along the way an extra parameter (cookies) got added to the method.

So add an extra empty array and you should be good:

```
$response = $this->call('POST', '/api/v1/location', $this->test_1_create_tag, [], [], ['Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$tokenObject->token]);
```